# PHP 5.5.13 on CentOS 6.5 with yum

Tags: php, centos

I've got problems with installing PHP 5.5.13 (last stable build) on a CentOS 6.5 (64 bit) machine, through `yum`.

It is not a part of the CentOS, EPEL or REMI repos as far as I can see. I get 5.4.29 with either of those repositories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With distros such as RHEL and CentOS, they typically have a 7-10 year lifetime, it's difficult to keep them up to date with the latest versions of things. Your only options are to:

1. go without it
2. build it from source yourself
3. use a 3rd party repository that provides alternative packages

I typically go with #3. You can use this repo to install 5.5:

- https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

To install the repo:

```
$ sudo rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

To install the packages:

```
$ sudo yum install php55w php55w-opcache
```

This is one of many 3rd party repos that provide packages in this manner. Always make sure that you're OK with using these repos, prior to just jumping in and using them. Some are better than others, but I've never run into an issue with using their builds of packages.

#### Using remi repo

This repo does provide the 5.5 packages of PHP, you just need to know how to tell it that that's what you want.

*Setting up repo, if not already*

```
$ sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
$ sudo wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
$ sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

*This will upgrade PHP from 5.3.3 to PHP 5.4.24 (15. January 2014).*

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi update -y
```

If you want the newest PHP, version 5.5.x you must run the following command:

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 update -y
```

#### References

- [Upgrading PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 or 5.5 on CentOS 6.5 with Virtualmin](http://reviews.myhken.com/upgrading-php-from-5-3-x-to-5-4-x-or-5-5-x-on-centos-6-5-with-virtualmin/)

Comment: I have tried `$ sudo yum –enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 update -y`, but it want me to install 5.4.29. Does not make much sense. I have tried a lot of things to make it work from remi.

Comment: @Adionditsak - take the `remi,` out of the list, it's probably trying to update your base install of php.

Comment: I get  :

Error: Package: php55w-common-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 3rd party repos, there is SCL: 
https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL

The wiki is old, it currently supports php 5.6.
After installing SCL, do a "yum search rh-php56" and you will see all php 5.6 related packages.

The catch is that all SCL packages are not installed on the usual directories so they can co-exist with other versions. They install under /opt using in a chroot-like tree. It may be what you want or not.

Comment: As far as i can see the SCL repo only supports PHP 5.4.

Comment: @Adionditsak no, the wiki is old, it supports 5.6 and other newer stuff like postgresql 9.4

Comment: Ok, that sounds like it could be something, then!

Answer (score 0):

You won't typically find the latest releases of software in a distro's package manager.  Unless a package has critical security patches, the version that is available via the package manager was the must current version when the release went into a testing [freeze](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/squeeze/sect.release-lifecycle.html).

> Freeze - During the freeze period, development of the Testing
>   distribution is blocked; no more automatic updates are allowed. Only
>   the Release Managers are then authorized to change packages, according
>   to their own criteria. The purpose is to prevent the appearance of new
>   bugs by introducing new versions; only thoroughly examined updates are
>   authorized when they correct significant bugs.

You'll have to either build `php` from source, create you own rpm/repo or find a third party that has already built an rpm and is making it available